# How to identify cross-job skills?

Tags: yakuza-like-a-dragon

In Yakuza: Like a Dragon I've done experimenting with the job system and have found some skills are usable on other jobs once they've been acquired.

Is there any way to tell which skills work like this without switching jobs and seeing if they're still available?

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting jobs, you can view the skills this job can acquire. On this screen, the red skills are ones that apply to the character, and exslusive to the job

[image]

Note, Eri's Starter skill "healing Vibration" is red, meaning she can use it no matter what job she has.

Each job always has around 2 character skills, so leveling up every job can make any character pretty versatile.